# How to Pass and Retrieve Datatables from android App to .NET Webservice

Tags: android, asp.net, excel, web-services

I m creating an Android App For my ASP.NET Web Application.. In my ASP.NET Application, Users will upload an Excel File (Or DataTable) to the .asmx WebService.. The code in Webservice checks the file and create another Excel File which contains the error Info abt the uploaded File.. Then the User can be able to Download the Error Excel File to rectify the Errors.. The same thing, I want to implement in Android Application..

My Doubts are..

```
1. Can I upload the Excel File without using any Excel DLL files.. (Coz I dont want to purchase Excel S/W)
2. If Not, Is there any open source alternatives to Excel which works good in Android?? Or can I able to create the DataTable in Android and Pass it to my WebService???
```

Please Help..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `jspreadsheet` library to handle excel files in android. It works fine. You can read more [here](http://www.independentsoft.de/jspreadsheet/index.html).

Comment: Can I use jExcelApi for Excel

Comment: As I read from this: http://jexcelapi.sourceforge.net/ , `JExcel` doesn't support .xlsx so it just supports excel 2003 and before.